# GCC __atomic functions: _n suffix vs explicit width, e.g. _4

Tags: c, gcc, atomic, intrinsics

The GCC `__atomic` API has multiple functions ending in `_n`, e.g.

```
__atomic_load_n 
__atomic_store_n
```

The compiler also supports intrinsitcs with `n` replaced by 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 (which you have to infer exist from the docs - IMO the docs are pretty hazy for `__atomic`s and should be improved!).  When an explicit number is used this tells the compiler the width of the data the atomic operation should operate on. When `_n` is used I'm presuming the compiler infers the width from the type passed if it can, or errors otherwise.

I checked this last statement by passing a `void*` to `__atomic_load_n` and it complained, which wasn't a big surprise.

So my questions are:

- Is what I have said correct?
- Is there any reason not to use the `_n` version except in the case that you have some opaque pointer and need to explicitly tell the compiler how wide it's pointee is?
- Are there any other subtleties I'm missing with this stuff?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the `_n` versions exist at all; I think `n` is a placeholder in the docs for the size of the object you are trying to load.

Comment: They actually work.  Try

    `int main()
    {
        int i = 6;
        int j = __atomic_load_n(&i, 0);   
        return j;
    }`

in Wandbox: http://melpon.org/wandbox. Hence my comment about the docs :)

Comment: Hmm, so it does. It might do overloading, even in C, since it's a compiler intrinsic and not a real function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what it's doing. I'm just curious to know the official story on this stuff.

Comment: Another confusing this is why there's a function `__atomic_load` - which takes different parameters - but this one has no explicit specialisation!